# Report generated by a date range in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to generate a report that totals the number of billable days something is being stored in my warehouse. So far I have a pivot table set up with a day counter.

```
 =IF(F3 < G3, G3 - F3, TODAY() - F3)
```

This is the code I want to modify to do perform this task.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim i, LastRow
 LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 2 To LastRow

             If UCase(Cells(i, "J").Value) >= "START DATE" AND <= "END DATE" Then
                 Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
                 Sheets("Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
             End If

         Next

 End Sub
```

What I'm attempting to create is a macro that allows me to enter a date range like '12/7/2014 to 20/7/2014' and have the report sum columns from multiple sheets within that range. Could anyone point me to some documentation or write some benign vba to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: This could be tough since you didn't provide something you've tried. So even if we could come up with something, we're not sure if you'll grasp the idea. If you can revise your question with additional details with specific issue with a code you've tried, that would be great. As is, your question is off topic.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been able to figure out how to go about this yet. The question is how do you select rows based on a date range? I can figure out how to move the rows once selected. I have that code working already in another macro. I just need to know how to select rows based on a start date and an end date. Could someone please show me some basic code?

Comment: Just check that the test cell's date is between the start and end dates.  In your code above you are checking strings, not dates; and your second comparison is malformed.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Sub TestRun()
Dim rSheet As Worksheet
Dim sSheet As Worksheet
Dim mSheet As Worksheet
Dim rRow As Long
Dim sRow As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim nRow As Long
Dim mRow As Long
Set mSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set rSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Received")
Set sSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shipped")
rRow = rSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sRow = sSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
mRow = mSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
mSheet.Range("A7:G" & mRow).ClearContents
mRow = mSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With rSheet
    .Range("A1:N" & rRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheet5.Range("B3"), Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                Criteria2:="<=" & Sheet5.Range("B4")
    .Range("F2:F" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("A" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("B2:B" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("B" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("J2:J" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("C" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("D2:D" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("D" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("N2:N" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("E" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("A2:A" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("G" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
mRow = mSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With sSheet
    .Range("A1:N" & rRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheet5.Range("B3"), Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                Criteria2:="<=" & Sheet5.Range("B4")
    .Range("F2:F" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("A" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("B2:B" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("B" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("J2:J" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("C" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("D2:D" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("D" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("N2:N" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("E" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("A2:A" & rRow).Copy
        mSheet.Range("G" & mRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
For i = 7 To mRow
    mSheet.Cells(i, "F") = mSheet.Cells(i, "D") * mSheet.Cells(i, "E")
Next
mRow = mSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
mSheet.Range("D" & mRow + 3) = "TOTAL GROSS LBS"
mSheet.Range("E" & mRow + 3) = "TOTAL DAYS"
mSheet.Range("F" & mRow + 3) = "TOTAL BILLABLE LBS"
mSheet.Range("D" & mRow + 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(mSheet.Range("D7:D" & mRow))
mSheet.Range("E" & mRow + 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(mSheet.Range("E7:E" & mRow))
mSheet.Range("F" & mRow + 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(mSheet.Range("F7:F" & mRow))
If Not Right(Sheet5.Range("B2"), 1) = "\" Then Sheet5.Range("B2") = Sheet5.Range("B2") & "\"
mSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    Sheet5.Range("B2") & "\" & Sheet5.Range("D2"), Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```